# PHP to communicate with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Static Page A has a form with an action submitting to a *Authorization page* B which is a dynamic page. After authorization, B will redirect to a *callback url* C which is passed to B by A.

Besides redirecting to page C, B also post some parameters indicated the auth states. **uin** is a most important parameter that will be used in the content of page C namely the scripts. The scripts need **uin** to send Ajax request later. Question is **how can I pass *uin* to the static page C?**

A quick and dirty idea I got is to wrap the static page C with a PHP file, and output the data in a hidden `div` for example:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("callback.html")
$div = "<div stype='display:none' uin={$_POST['uin']}></div>"
//add this div to $html and print it, need a little more work to figure out how to do this
?>
```

Is there a better way of doing this , because this is  sort of  'idiot' I think...

Comment: why not just use a location header to C with a url param? I think JS can access them(? if not you could place it after a hash instead)

Comment: Typo: `stype` ---> `style`.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:  (with `stype` typo fixed)

```
$div = "<div style=\"display:none\" uin={$_POST['uin']}></div>";
```

Looking at this code, the biggest problem I can see with it is that you're outputting a `$_POST` value without doing any escaping on it.

This a potential security threat; consider what would happen if someone provided a form that posted to your site, with the `uin` value set to a string of HTML code, starting with `>` to close the `div`. Their code would appear in your site, exactly as if you'd put it there. With a careful bit of styling, they could use this make your site look and behave however they want. Not great.

You can fix that by using wrapping the `$_POST` variable in `html_entities()` so it is properly escaped when it is output to the site.

Or, in this case, since it is (or appears to be) a numeric ID value, you could simply cast it as an int to ensure that it contains no unwanted data, no matter what the actual post data contains:

```
$uin = (int)$_POST['uin'];
```

...and then use `$uin` in the output rather than the raw post data.

The second point I'd make is one of validity. `uin` is not a valid HTML attribute. It may work, but it's not valid. The correct standards-compliant way to do custom attributes in HTML is to use a data attribute, like so:

```
$div = "<div style=\"display:none\" data-uin={$uin}></div>";
```

... ie the names of all custom attributes should start with `data-`

This is recommended because it allows you to have custom attributes with the same name as real attributes without risking any problems. eg you could have `data-style`, without colliding with the real `style` attribute.

It also means that the HTML spec can have new attributes added to it without risking clashes with other people's code. eg if a future version of HTML includes a `uin` attribute that future browsers use to do something clever with the element, it would cause problems with your code. Those problems would not happen if you use `data-uin`. (okay, so `uin` is an unlikely name for a new standard HTML attribute, but the point stands)

Answer (score 0):

You have an syntax errors in your php code you need to mask the quotes around your inline style and you missed to add some colons:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("callback.html");
$div = "<div style=\"display:none\" uin={$_POST['uin']}></div>";
//add this div to $html and print it, need a little more work to figure out how to do this
echo($html); // print variable $html
echo($div); // print variable $div
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should store parameters from page B in user session. Than on page C you can use these parameters (after calling `session_start()` before anything is outputted to the browser). Also, if you are using javascript, consider placing uin in javascript variable instead of html div. Something like `<script type="text/javascript">var uin = 123; </script>`.